# URL parsing through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need url parts like

```
www.example.com/education/tutorial/php.html

to

MainFolder=education

SubFolder=tutorial

PageName=php
```

and

```
www.example.com/jobs.html

to 

MainFolder=null

SubFolder=null

PageName=jobs
```

How to handle these two situations.

I have using the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?Page=$3&SubFolder=$2&MainFolder=$1
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?Page=$1
```

But it is not working in both conditions. Works only with only one.

Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?Page=$3&SubFolder=$2&MainFolder=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?Page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a start anchor on both rules. As I can see, the second rule you have will always be caught.

Your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?PageName=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?PageName=$3&SubFolder=$2&MainFolder=$1 [NC,L]
```

Notice how I changed `Page` to `PageName`, added the flags `NC` and `L` and added the `^` anchor to the start of your rules. `NC` makes the match case-insensitive and `L` haults rule matching for the current directory. As well, the `^` searches from the start of the URL, not anywhere (which you currently have).